# Can custom taxonomies items have attached properties?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, tags

Let's say for (a classic) example that I want to create an **event** custom **post type**, which will have assigned some specific fields/properties. One of them: **location venue**.

Location venue, which I'm thinking should be a tag in a custom taxonomy, would have, besides the title, also an **url** and a pair of **coordinates**, for example.

So, questions are:

1. Would this be a sensible approach?
2. How would I go implementing it?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a good idea as it would let you query by location etc. I don't know what you plan to use the co-ordinates for, but it makes no sense to have them attached to an event (unless that event is a one-off in the middle of a field, but I guess that would be an edge case?).

As for implementation, this is a very useful plugin:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/taxonomy-metadata/

It allows you to add/get/update/delete term meta just as though it were post meta

So you could do something like this (just to give the idea, may not work 100%) :

```
  add_action( 'locations_edit_form_fields', 'edit_locations');
  function edit_locations($location)
  {
    $url = get_term_meta($location->term_id, 'url', true); 
    ?>
   <tr class="form-field">
      <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="url">url</label></th>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="url" id="url" 
            value="<?php echo $url; ?>"/>
        <p class="description">Add url here.</p>
      </td>
  </tr> 
  }
```

to set the information, and then use $_POST to update the meta thusly:

```
 add_action( 'edited_locations', 'update_location', 10, 2);
 function update_location($location_term_id)
 {
   if (!$location_term_id) 
       return;

   if (isset($_POST['url'])) {
      //you may wish to sanitize this value (not sure if it has been already?)
      update_term_meta($location_term_id, 'url', $_POST['url']);
   }
 }
```

Further reading: http://en.bainternet.info/2011/custom-taxonomies-extra-fields

Comment: The coordinates wouldn't be attached to the event, they would be attached to the venue - which is assigned to the event, the venue itself would have different properties - like website and coordinates, a description etc

Comment: I think we agree, in that case. sorry if that's not clear from the above.

Answer (score 1):

As others have already said, no, terms can not have additional properties attached to them. A term in a taxonomy is just a label for a group of items.

So, I would instead make *venue* a second custom post type and then connect it to the *event* post type using Posts 2 Posts: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/

Comment: Problem is? (how) can you then search for venues? - display all events that take place in a certain venue, like you could do with a taxonomy term (tags/categories)?

Comment: That's what P2P is all about. The only thing it doesn't have out of the box yet is rewrite rules.

Comment: So the URLs would look like this: `http://example.com/?connected_type=events-to-venues&connected_items=123` where 123 is the id of a venue. But you can add your own rewrite rules to make them prettier, say `http://example.com/venue/some-venue-slug/events/`

Answer (score 0):

The coordinates could be added using metaboxes. Check out the example here http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box#Example

Answer (score 0):

What you're wanting is term meta data, e.g. two events are tagged at "The Big place", and "The Big Place" has coordinates etc attached to it, that are pulled in by the two events.

Unfortunately WordPress does not have a facility for term meta. You can add it via plugins, alternatively, you could have a post type location-meta, set up to not be public and not show in public listings, that you can attach the meta to, then assing it to relevant term tag.

Or you could make your taxonomy heirarchical, and add child terms with names such as 'coordinates-X-Y-Z' etc and filter them out when viewing the taxonomy terms.